# RSA encryption/decryption of long files

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I want to encrypt/decrypt a long file with RSA (I know AES is better, but this is just for a comparison) in openssl/libcrypto. I am splitting the input file into blocks of size `numBlocks = inputFileLength/maxlen+1` where `maxlen = 200`. I can successfully encode and decode in the same loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++)
{
    int bytesDone = i * maxlen;
    int remainingLen = inLength - bytesDone;
    int thisLen; 

    if (remainingLen > maxlen)
    {
        thisLen = maxlen;
    } else
    {
        thisLen = remainingLen;
    }
    if((encBytes=RSA_public_encrypt(thisLen, data + bytesDone, encryptdata + bytesDone,
                                    rsa_public, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)) == -1)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
    if((decBytes=RSA_private_decrypt(encBytes, encryptdata + bytesDone, decryptdata + bytesDone,
                                     rsa_private, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)) == -1)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
}
```

However, I want to save the encoded buffer `encryptdata` in a binary file, reading the binary file back and decryption. I try to do this as follows:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++)
{
    int bytesDone = i * maxlen;
    int remainingLen = inLength - bytesDone;
    int thisLen; 

    if (remainingLen > maxlen)
    {
        thisLen = maxlen;
    } else
    {
        thisLen = remainingLen;
    }
    if((encBytes=RSA_public_encrypt(thisLen, data + bytesDone, encryptdata + bytesDone,
                                    rsa_public, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)) == -1)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }

}

writeFile("encoded.bin",encryptdata,strlen(encryptdata));
size_t size;
unsigned char *readData = readFile("encoded.bin", size);
int inputlen = size;
for (int i = 0; (i * keylen) < inputlen; i++) //keylen = 256
{
    int bytesDone = i * keylen;


    if((decBytes=RSA_private_decrypt(encBytes, readData + bytesDone, decryptdata + bytesDone,
                                     rsa_private, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)) == -1)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
}
printf("Decrypted text: %s",decryptdata);
```

The `readFile` and `writeFile` functions are as follows:

```
void writeFile(char *filename, unsigned char *file, size_t fileLength
{

FILE *fd = fopen(filename, "wb");
if(fd == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

size_t bytesWritten = fwrite(file, 1, fileLength, fd);

if(bytesWritten != fileLength) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write file\n");
    exit(1);
}

fclose(fd);
```

}

```
unsigned char* readFile(char *filename, size_t size) {
FILE *fd = fopen(filename, "rb");
if(fd == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

// Determine size of the file
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t fileLength = ftell(fd);
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
size = fileLength;
// Allocate space for the file
unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(fileLength);

// Read the file into the buffer
size_t bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, fileLength, fd);

if(bytesRead != fileLength) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
    exit(1);
}

fclose(fd);

return buffer;
```

}

However, the decryption fails with the error message `segmentation fault (core dump)` and the decrypt function only returns `-1` for every block. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It isn't "just better" to use AES it is that RSA is not designed to encrypt data longer than the key. I the case where asymmetric encryption is needed the way to handle long data is with [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Answer (score 2):

ReadFile modifies the parameter "size" which is passed by value, thus when the readfile function returns, size is not affected.

I would change readfile proto as follows :

```
unsigned char* readFile(char *filename, size_t *size)
```

and then change the call into

```
unsigned char *readData = readFile("encoded.bin", &size);
```

and finally modify the readFile size update to

```
size = fileLength;
```

Comment: the "segmentation fault" error is gone. But the decrypted buffer is null.

Comment: There are parts missing in the source code, for instance the "decryptdata" has not clearly been allocated in what i see, i'm assuming it is done somewhere else, it would be nice if you could drop the full source code.

Comment: While this answer helps the OP (in the same way as helping someone jump off a bridge) it in general is not helpful because using RSA (or EC) for data larger than the key size is not correct usage ad certainly should not be used in production.

Comment: unsigned char* decryptdata = (unsigned char*) malloc (inputlen+1);

Comment: Actually, as far as i know, crypted rsa data is more than one byte bigger than the clear data, depending on the crypt key, there might be a problem there

Answer (score 0):

Your have various technical errors in your code like doing a `strlen(..)` on binary data in this statement:

```
writeFile("encoded.bin",encryptdata,strlen(encryptdata));
```

`encryptdata` is binary data that can include `0` that would be interprited as a string termination by `strlen(..)`

But the main problem is that you try to use **RSA** as a block cipher. Your encrypted blocks are bigger that what you encrypt, but you don't handle that in your code. You might be able to get your code to handle this, but the right approach is to use ciphers invented for bulk encryption, like **AES**. When you do that, you automatically get support for 'blocking' out of the box.

In addition to this you get something like a factor 1000 faster encryption.